# Allow users to change and save a background image on a web page in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I would like users to have the option to change the background image on my website, so I found some code that allows them to do this. It allows them to paste a URL of a image of their choice in a textbox(input):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changebackground(){
    var url = document.getElementById('bgchanger').value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="bgchanger" placeholder="Change Background Add URL" />
<input type="button" onclick="changebackground();" value="Change!" />
```

It all works but when the user leaves the site or hits refresh the background image goes back to white (default)

I was wondering if we could save the users background image for the next time they visit the site.

I have made a demo:

> **DEMO**:  http://goo.gl/253IN
>
> Username: **demo**
>
> Password: **demo1**

Thank you in advance!

PS I am not an expert (yet :D) on HTML and Javascrpit so I will not be able to understand really complex code

Comment: store the setting in cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with localStorage

```
    var defaultImage = "http://...";
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('back') ? "url('"+localStorage.getItem('back')+"')" : "url('"+defaultImage+"')";
  function changebackground(){
      var url =  document.getElementById('bgchanger').value;
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
      localStorage.setItem('back',url);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

to accomplish this .. you have to place a cookie on the users computer then check if the cookie is set and retrieve it's value ,...

here is a jquery plugin for cookies
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

first you creat the cookie

```
$.cookie('background_image', url , { expires: 7 });// will expire in 7 days
```

then you check if that cookie is set

```
if(typeof($.cookie('background_image')) != 'undefined'){
    var users_old_back_ground = $.cookie('background_image');
    $('body').css ({ "background-image" : "url('" + users_old_back_ground + "')"}); //jquery : selecting the body tag ... then using css() to set the bg
}else{
    // do something else because the user doesnt have the cookie 
}
```

and try to enhance your previous code and use jquery instead of plain javascript

Comment: your more than welcome .. try to learn jquery , it's so easy and powerful . :) good luck

Comment: @codeiz try to learn javascript, it's easie and maybe let you make jQuery more powerful ;)

Comment: @yckart , why am i doing some thing wrong here ?! BTW jquery is a javascript library :)

Comment: @codeiz Nothing! However, I think it's better to bring newbies closer to plain javascript, instead of referring them to a library that will let them never understand how javascript works...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to use localStorage. I've written a jQuery Plugin to make handling it easier. Take a Look at the examples. https://github.com/yckart/jquery.storage.js

Comment: `You can optional include a $.cookie plugin
to support older browsers (e.q. IE lt 7)` .. so it doesn't support all browsers ..

Comment: @GioL I think that using cookies is not longer a need: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage