# Changing Header Background Image on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I currently have setup the background image of the header section of each page using CSS:

```
.banner {
  background: url('img/banners/homebanner1.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 2em 0;
}
```

Ideally i'd like to add a bit of flexibility by allowing the user to change the background image of any page in the UI by uploading an image, rather than having to go in to the CSS to change it.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: question has been answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176870/allow-users-to-change-and-save-a-background-image-on-a-web-page-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by wp option using dashboard widget, first add this to functions.php of your theme folder

```
function add_michal_dashboard_widget(){
wp_add_dashboard_widget(
  'michal_dashboard_widget',         // slug.
  'Michal Dashboard Widget',         // title
  'michal_dashboard_widget_function' // widget code
  );  
}

function register_mysettings() {
  register_setting( 'michal-option-group', 'background' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );

function michal_dashboard_widget_function(){
if (isset($_POST['background'])) update_option( 'background', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['background'])); 
?> 
<?php settings_fields( 'michal-option-group' ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( 'michal-option-group' ); ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<table class="form-table">
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row">Background</th>
<td><input type="text" name="background" value="<?php echo get_option('background'); ?>" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

<?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>

<?php       
} 
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_michal_dashboard_widget' );
```

then add style to theme header (most probably header.php)

```
<style>
.banner{
background: url("<?php echo get_option('background'); ?>") no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
padding: 2em 0;
}
</style>
```

One more thing, be careful while adding to functions.php do not leave new lines char between ?>